# How do I export a redux reducer that uses a prepare function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am currently working on a anecdotes application, and anytime a user votes on a certain anecdote, it should display a notification then disappear 10 seconds later, however, I am struggling to export my reducer that uses the `prepare` function that is suppose to, I think, get my *multiple* arguments ready for the actual reducer. Here is my code in **question**:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const notificationSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'notification',
  initialState: '',
  reducers: {
    test: {
      createNotification(state, action) {
        console.log(action)
      },
      prepare(...args) {
        return {
          payload: args
        }
      }
    }
}})

export const { createNotification } = notificationSlice.actions
export default notificationSlice.reducer
```

I thought I could just `export const { test.createNotification } = notificationSlice.actions` but that does not work due to the **dot** in the variable name.

How would I then export my `createNotification` reducer since `test` is the first property of the `reducers` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I just name the reducer `createNotification` with two key values of `reducer` and `prepare`

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const notificationSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'notification',
  initialState: '',
  reducers: {
    createNotification: {
      reducer(state, action) {
        console.log(action)
      },
      prepare(...args) {
        return {
          payload: args
        }
      }
    }
}})

export const { createNotification } = notificationSlice.actions
export default notificationSlice.reducer
```